# Natural deduction: $(\neg q \to\neg p)\vdash(p\to q)$ without Modus Tollens

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Can anyone help me to obtain this result in natural deduction, without using modus tollens:

$$(\neg q \to \neg p)  \vdash  ( p \to q)$$

Comment: What do you mean with *without using modus tollens*?

Comment: And what axioms are allowed?

Comment: you know if I use that rule then it would be very easy. I mean in the derivation, this rule shouldn't be used

Comment: All others. Like not introduction, not elimation, conjutions, discjunctions, contradiction elimination ...

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Actually it is possible, but I just can't figure it out

Comment: Just to be sure, with *modus tollens* you mean $\to \text{ elimination}$, right?

Comment: Not exactly, Modus Tollens is something similar with that, but not the same

Comment: Then it goes something like this: you wanna prove an implication whose antecedent is $p$. Assume $p$. Now assume $\neg q$. Use $\to \text{ elim}$ to get $\neg p$. Now use $\bot \text{ intro}$ and $\neg \text{ intro}$ to get $\neg \neg q$. Conclude. Can you handle the details?

Comment: Yeah I think that's the correct answer. But can you be a little bit more specific in details? I mean while working inside the assumption boxes and giving references

Comment: I didn't mention the $\land$ introduction. I don't have the time to give a proper answer now. Maybe in 30 minutes.

Comment: Details that are more specific than what @GitGud wrote will depend on the exact details of the precise variant of natural deduction you have to work within. Unless you share the _exact_ definition of your proof system, you won't get anything better than this except perhaps by pure chance.

Comment: ... and even so, the last half of Git's proof sketch (where you get from having assumed $p$ and derived $\neg p$ to concluding $q$) is itself sensitive to minor variations in the formalization of natural deduction.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah you right. That's the answer Git Gud   wrote that I am looking for. I just need more deatails

Comment: It helps more to actually specify what the rules say in symbols than to just use nicknames like "not elimination". For example, instead of saying "not elimination" you would tell us "$\lnot$p, (q$\land$$\lnot$q) $\vdash$ p". Why? Because "not elimination" could mean another different rule. The "not elimination" rule that Hunan used would go "$\lnot$$\lnot$p $\vdash$ p" in a similar symbol scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. I've used modus ponens ($\rightarrow$ Elim), the law of non-contradiction ($\bot$ Intro), reductio ad absurdum ($\lnot$ Intro), and direct proof ($\rightarrow$ Intro). Depending on your system, you can probably skip 6 and go straight to 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used a Hilbert proof style from the book "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" of Elliot Mendelson. It's a really cool book:

1. (¬q→¬p) Hypothesis
2. (¬q→¬p)→((¬q→p)→q) Axiom
3. (¬q→p)→q Modus Ponens (1, 2)
4. p→(¬q→p) Axiom
5. p→q Transitivity (3, 4)

Transitivity a→b, b→c ⊢ a→c:

1. a→b Hypothesis
2. b→c Hypothesis
3. (b→c)→(a→(b→c)) Axiom
4. a→(b→c) Modus Ponens (2, 4)
5. (a→(b→c))→((a→b)→(a→c)) Axiom
6. (a→b)→(a→c) Modus Ponens (4, 5)
7. a→c Modus Ponens (1, 6)